# Going back to an earlier index in list iteration

Tags: python, list, for-loop, iteration

I have this loop over a list:

```
MyList = ["test", "test2", "test3", "test4", "test5", "test6", "test7"]

for item in MyList:
    print(item) # output: [test, test2, test3, test4, test5, test6, test7]
    if item == "test7":
        pass  # ?
```

Now in here if `item == "test7"` I want to go back to the third item (`"test3"`) and go count up again.

How can I do that?

I have to use a `for` loop. I can't really use a `while` loop.

Comment: Why can't you use a `while` loop?

Comment: The list iterator doesn't expose any methods to do this, nor is this part of the Python iterator protocol. So the *most sensible way to loop like this* is to just use a while-loop. The alternative is to write your own iterator that exposes such an interface if you really want to use a for loop, but that would probably be an over engineered solution

Comment: `for item in MyList[:MyList.index("test7")+1] + MyList[MyList.index("test3"):]:` does what you say you want, but I doubt it does what you *actually* want.

Comment: Do you have to go back when you are at the *last* item (which happens to be `"test7"`) or specifically if the item is `"test7"` even if there are more items after that?

Comment: What should happen after counting up again is finished?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

change the
new_start_index to whatever you want and just do another for loop.

```
MyList = ["test", "test2", "test3", "test4", "test5", "test6", "test7"]

for item in MyList:
    print(item)
    if item == "test7":
        new_start_index = 3
        # Continue the loop from the new_start_index
        for new_item in MyList[new_start_index:]:
            print(new_item)
```

Answer (score -2):

try this...i don't know if its what you want.

```
MyList = ["test", "test2", "test3", "test4", "test5", "test6", "test7"] starting_index = 2 

for i, item in enumerate(MyList):
    print(item)
    if item == "test7":
        for j in range(starting_index, len(MyList)):
           
            print("Processing:", MyList[j])
        break
```

Answer (score -3):

You can use indexing and for loop range.

```
MyList = ["test", "test2", "test3", "test4", "test5", "test6", "test7"]

for i in range(len(MyList)):
    print(MyList[i]) # output: [test, test2, test3, test4, test5, test6, test7]
    if item == "test7":
       i = i - 1
```

#so if you want to previous element, if i is not = 0 then is MyList[i-1]
pass  # ?

Comment: Thanks for providing a potential answer! Always great to hear from new contributors. One thing that might be leading to downvotes is that it seems you are asking a question as part of it. If you have open questions, then it is likely the answer you provide is not complete. Try asking the question in the comments to the original question, then editing your answer once you get more clarity from the poster.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).